# Can I release the snapshot created by Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.DataTarget?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, heap-memory

My application that is having a memory leak, but the leak only happens at the customer site (of course) in a production environment where I'm not allowed to install Visual Studio or any kind of memory debugging tool.

So I added a button that allows the user to request a heap analysis when they see the memory usage go "too high".  When they click this button, my application does this:

```
using DataTarget dataTarget = DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach(Environment.ProcessId);
ClrRuntime clr = dataTarget.ClrVersions.First().CreateRuntime();
```

My application then analyzes the information in clr.Heap to figure out what's happening.

That all works fine, except that after I've done my analysis and I'm trying to clean up, I get this error:

```
Unable to kill the target process: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime.WindowsProcessDataReader.Dispose(Boolean _)
```

Is there any way to convince Windows that I created the "process", so I should be allowed to destroy it?  Is there a better way to get to the heap information that doesn't involve making a copy of my application's entire memory (which doubles its memory usage, making a problem twice as bad)?

Comment: Have you tried using:

var processId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.CreateSnapshotAndAttach(processId))
{
}

Comment: You also could try connecting in passive mode, but the data will be constantly changing.

using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(process.Id, 10000, AttachFlag.Passive))
{
}

Comment: @JoshH I've updated the code to show that it is passing the argument "Environment.ProcessID".  And the documentation says "ClrMD does NOT support inspecting a running process and will produce undefined behavior when attempting to do so."

Comment: What if you were to try something like:

using (var dataTarget = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(pid, 5000, AttachFlag.Passive))
{
    ClrInfo runtimeInfo = dataTarget.ClrVersions[0];
    var runtime = runtimeInfo.CreateRuntime();

   // get what you need from runtime here.
}